# Make server not to use VPN as a default gateway

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, routing, wireguard

I have a local server connected to a remote WireGuard VPN. The server routes all its traffic through the VPN (wg0 interface), but I need it to use the VPN only to communicate with other members of the VPN network and the eth0 interface for the rest of the traffic.

How can I achieve this?

VPN server wireguard config:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.66.66.1/24,fd42:42:42::1/64
ListenPort = 60207
PrivateKey = privatekey
PostUp = iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 60207 -j ACCEPT
PostUp = iptables -I FORWARD -i eth0 -o wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostUp = iptables -I FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostUp = iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostUp = ip6tables -I FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostUp = ip6tables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D INPUT -p udp --dport 60207 -j ACCEPT
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i eth0 -o wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostDown = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = ip6tables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostDown = ip6tables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

### Client
[Peer]
PublicKey = pubkey
PresharedKey = preshardkey
AllowedIPs = 10.66.66.3/32,fd42:42:42::3/128

### Client
...
### Client
...
```

Client (local server) wireguard config:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = privatekey
Address = 10.66.66.3/32,fd42:42:42::3/128

[Peer]
PublicKey = pubkey
PresharedKey = preshardkey
Endpoint = endpoint:60207
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0,::/0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> [Peer]
> AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0,::/0
> ```

The `wg-quick` tool will install kernel routes corresponding to every peer's AllowedIPs. So the easiest way to avoid having wg-quick install a default route would be to **not specify** a default route in AllowedIPs – change the catch-all 0.0.0.0/0 and ::/0 (which represent the "default" routes for IPv4 and IPv6 respectively) to be just the list of your network prefixes and that's what will be routed.

(Technically the two parameters are independent, so it's possible to use the `Table=` option to have wg-quick put the routes elsewhere – or to not install any routes at all – in combination with `PostUp=` that would add the necessary routes. In practice however that's not really needed for basic workstation clients; it'll be easier to just edit AllowedIPs.)

---

On a different note, if the VPN is only for accessing a local network, then you shouldn't nee_ any of the 'MASQUERADE' rules on the server; the local network should instead have a regular route back to the VPN network.